# Apple Mach-O for libAppLovinSdk.a in cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, applovin

I am trying to display AppLovin sdk in my cocos2d project in Xcode and I'm currently unable to debug this Apple Mach-O error as described below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMTimeGetSeconds", referenced from:
      -[ALVideoViewController timeLeft] in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALVideoViewController.o)
      -[ALVideoViewController percentViewed] in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALVideoViewController.o)
  "_CMTimeMakeWithSeconds", referenced from:
      -[ALVideoViewController createCountdownTimeObserver] in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALVideoViewController.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      ___50-[ALInterstitialViewController prepareForVideoAd:]_block_invoke in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALInterstitialViewController.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      ___53-[ALInterstitialViewController moviePlayerDidFinish:]_block_invoke in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALInterstitialViewController.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      ___50-[ALInterstitialViewController prepareForVideoAd:]_block_invoke in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALInterstitialViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libAppLovinSdk.a(ALInterstitialViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I went to build phases -> add other -> Selected libAppLovinSdk.a file from the finder displayed.

I also set the value of Build Active Architectures only to NO and removed arm64 from architectures. There is no i386 architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `CoreMedia` and `MediaPlayer` frameworks.

(I found this out by Googling for `CMTimeGetSeconds` and `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` and seeing what section of the Apple docs got hits, however the `CM` and `MP` prefixes should be enough to tell you).